# Bash multithread speed issue

Tags: multithreading, bash, shell, openssl, brute-force

I'm doing a script that decodes a coded password so I can see the original password. The problem is that the sequencial code is faster than the multithread code. The sequencial code lasts 12 seconds and the multithread lasts 20 seconds. Why?

I'm executing on elementary OS 64 bit (ubuntu 14.04) with 8 GB Ram + i5-2450M (4CPU ~ 2,4Ghz) + SSD.

Sequencial code.

```
#!/bin/bash

space="a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"

if [  $# -le 1 ]
then 
    echo "Ussage: " $0 SALT PASSWORD_CODED
    exit
fi
echo $2
echo $1
for i in $space
do
for j in $space
do
for k in $space
do
    #echo $i$j$k
    variable=$(openssl passwd -crypt -salt "$1" "$i$j$k")
    if [ "$variable" = $2 ]
        then
        echo password found: $i$j$k
        exit
    fi
done
done
done
```

Multithread code.

```
space="a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"

if [  $# -le 1 ]
then 
    echo "Ussage: " $0 SALT PASSWORD_CODED
    exit
fi

calculate1 () 
{
    for i in $space
    do
    for j in $space
    do
    for k in $space
    do
        variable=$(openssl passwd -crypt -salt "$1" "$k$j$i")
        if [ "$variable" = $2 ]
            then
            echo password found: $k$j$i
            date
            exit
        fi
    done
    done
    done
}

calculate2 () 
{
    for i in $space
    do
    for j in $space
    do
    for k in $space
    do
        variable2=$(openssl passwd -crypt -salt "$1" "$i$j$k")
        if [ "$variable2" = $2 ]
            then
            echo password found: $i$j$k
            date
            exit
        fi
    done
    done
    done
}

date
calculate1 $1 $2 &
calculate2 $1 $2 &

echo waiting
wait
```

Why the single thread and sequencial code is faster?

Could I use C code instead of bash? 
What is similar as `variable2=$(openssl passwd -crypt -salt "$1" "$i$j$k")` in C?

Comment: You do realize that your parallel version doesn't partition the work between the two processes, but rather, makes each one do all the work?

Comment: Yes but i assume that both works at same speed. First one starts left side and second starts from right side. So when they have done half work they already have the password and printed it because they passed all combinations

Comment: if both "processes" are attempting to find the same answer and one starts from left and the other on the right it would be incorrect to assume the speed of both processes would be the same. Run the process once from the "Sequencial code" starting on the right side and see how long it takes, I assume it will take close to twenty seconds. (Think about why that is and find a better way to split your work.) As previously mentioned in the comments you are not splitting the work load and if you were to actually split it this way you may increase or decrease your chances of find the answer faster.

Comment: @user2911701: Your analysis is wrong. Both processes start at `aaa` and end at `zzz`. When they've both done half the work, you'll have cracked any password that starts or ends with any letter `a` through `m` -- so, three-quarters of all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example to partition the work between 26 processes:

```
#!/bin/bash

s="$1"; p="$2"
printf -v space "%s " {a..z}
echo $s $p

calc() {
  for j in $space; do
    for k in $space; do
      variable=$(openssl passwd -crypt -salt "$s" "$i$j$k")
      if [ "$variable" = "$s$p" ]; then
        echo password found: $i$j$k
        return
      fi
    done
  done
}

for i in $space; do
  calc &
done

wait
```

---

Test: `./script.sh 6 AGuqwGE0gkDg`

Output:

```
6 AGuqwGE0gkDg
password found: xde
```